# Should I write a unit test to check @NonNull contracts?

Tags: java, unit-testing

Today I had a discussion with some colleagues about unit tests. One controversial aspect was whether you need to unit test all the contracts of a function.

Example:

```
public void foo(@NonNull Type1 arg1, @NonNull Type2 arg2) {
  requireNonNull(arg1);
  requireNonNull(arg2);

  // ...
}
```

Though I do agree that it is a good idea to check the `@NonNull` contract in the implementation (the `Objects.requireNonNull` statements), I disagreed that you should write unit tests for it.

Here is an example:

```
 @Test(expected = NullpointerException.class)
 public void fooMustThrowIfArg1IsNull() {
   Type2 dummy = ...;
   foo(null, dummy);
 }
```

So far, I tried to concentrate more on the behavior of the code that you write. As far as I understand the TDD and BDD styles, you always start with a test, then implement just enough to pass the test, and so on. However, I have never seen a TDD or BDD practitioner starting with a test as above.

I agree that you should keep your unit tests as simple as possible to isolate different aspects (as few assertions as possible). But I fear that a test like `fooMustThrowIfArg1IsNull` has a higher maintenance cost than benefit, even if you neglect the time need to write it. The only exception that I see are tests for crucial APIs (e.g., the Java standard library implementation or Google Guava).

As the topic is highly opinionated, a simple yes or no answer is difficult. It would be helpful to support it with a link to an expert option with a clear recommendation on this topic. Possible sources:

- A style guide of a company with a deep testing culture (e.g., Google)
- A quote or code example by an acknowledged expert on testing

(I found search engines not really helpful and unfortunately I haven't read any books about testing yet.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well, there is no definite answer. However, checking the contracts of your code seems to a good idea. If there wasn't the boilerplate code...

There is one interesting approach that I found in [Google Guava's](https://code.google.com/p/guava-libraries/) sources. For example, this test is part of `SplitterTest.java`:

```
@GwtIncompatible("NullPointerTester")
public void testNullPointers() {
  NullPointerTester tester = new NullPointerTester();
  tester.testAllPublicStaticMethods(Splitter.class);
  tester.testAllPublicInstanceMethods(Splitter.on(','));
  tester.testAllPublicInstanceMethods(Splitter.on(',').trimResults());
}
```

So, at least the Google developers test their null contracts. (Grepping for `NullPointerTester` results in 335 hits.)

`NullPointerTester` assumes that constructors and methods that are not marked as `@Nullable` should immediately fail when `null` is passed in. They define failing as either throwing `NullPointerException` or `UnsupportedOperationException`.

I think it is a very nice trick. They get all the benefits of testing *fail fast* semantics but avoid writing lots of boring, mechanical tests.

So, should *you* write unit tests to check *fail fast* `@NonNull` contracts? Maybe it is better to let *reflection* do the job for you. :-)

Answer (score 2):

it depends on your contract. if your contract says: 'that method should throw an exception on null argument' then you should test it because that's the expected behavior. but if your contract says: 'that method works for not null arguments and it's behavior is undefined for null arguments' then you don't test it because it's out of scope. in the later case, all requireNonNull preconditions are added simply to enforce fail-fast policy and to make debugging easier